# How can I correct an invalid key type in Parse Cloud Code?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

We made a mistake in our client code where some users attempt to save a false boolean flag (by mistake) and others save a string to the same key in our Parse database.
I'm getting error code from Parse from everyone setting the false boolean as follows:

```
{"code":111,"error":"invalid type for key premiumType, expected string, but got boolean"}
```

Until we can release the next version of our client code, I want to intercept and correct this error IN CLOUD CODE. I'm trying this:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave('GameScore', function(request, response) {
console.log("Entered function");   
var premiumType = request.object.get("premiumType");
   if (premiumType) {
       request.object.set("premiumType", null);
         response.success();
   } else {
      response.success();
   }

});
```

But, the beforeSave function does not get entered unless the key type is correct, so I cannot modify the object here.

Are there any other locations where I can intercept this and modify the code in the cloud?

Comment: check with request.params.get("premiumType") instead of request.object.get("premiumType");

Comment: console.log never gets reached if premiumType is a bool so any changes below wouldn't change much